# Is it possible to insert a switch/case statement inside a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, laravel, switch-statement

I'm want to insert a switch/case statement inside a JavaScript class. In various cases, I'm trying to create a class that shows a specific step of a guided tour made with a library. So I asked myself if it is possible to insert this kind of statement inside a JavaScript class to execute depending on the PHP route name. Is it possible?

```
class TourUtils {
    constructor(routeName) {
        switch (routeName) {
            case "host":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    document
                        .querySelector(".dashboard__tour")
                        .addEventListener("click", () => {
                            window.TOUR.start();
                        });
                });
                break;
            case "Nuovo annuncio":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    window.TOUR.show("new-ad-page-intro-step");
                });
                break;
            case "Modifica annuncio":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    window.TOUR.show("new-ad-page-nineth-step");
                });
                break;
            case "Casa annuncio":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    if ($("#save").is(":visible"))
                        window.TOUR.show("mod-house-page-intro-step");
                });
                break;
            case "Nuova casa":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    window.TOUR.show("mod-house-page-second-step");
                });
                break;
            case "Modifica casa":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    window.TOUR.show("mod-price-page-intro-step");
                });
                break;
            case "Calendario":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    if ($(".update-btn").is(":visible"))
                        window.TOUR.show("final-step");
                    else if (!$(".update-btn").is(":visible")) {
                        window.TOUR.show("mod-price-page-second-step");
                    }
                });
                break;
            case "Aggiungi date":
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    window.TOUR.show("add-date-page-intro-step");
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should this be a class? It literally looks like a function with extra steps.

Comment: Don't hesitate to check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: the problem is the guided tour library that i'm using. it is developed for landing pages and not multi-page websites, the only way that i found is to show a specific step based on the php route name, but this code was in the index using blade sintax, and now i want to split the same logic in a js file that i just call on the index

Comment: Using switch inside a class constructor or method is possible, yes. Can you clarify what the issue is with your code? Does it work? If not, how does it fail?

Comment: Why put `$(document).ready` in each case statement? Shouldn't the code that calls your `TourUtils` have document ready triggered as well? Alternatively you can wrap the constructor's code with document ready so the switch/case statement is a little more readable.

Comment: the issue that i'm having is that the code doesn't trhow any error but at the same time the step that i'm calling doesn't show. I will try as suggested to remove document.ready to make the statements more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code to the following. Maybe that helps finding the problem of your code.

```
class TourUtils {
  constructor(routeName) {
    var routes = {
        "host": function () {
          document
            .querySelector(".dashboard__tour")
            .addEventListener("click", () => {
              window.TOUR.start();
            });
        },
        "Nuovo annuncio": "new-ad-page-intro-step",
        "Modifica annuncio": "new-ad-page-nineth-step",
        "Casa annuncio": function () {
          if ($("#save").is(":visible"))
            window.TOUR.show("mod-house-page-intro-step");
        },
        "Nuova casa": "mod-house-page-second-step",
        "Modifica casa": "mod-price-page-intro-step",
        "Calendario": function () {
          if ($(".update-btn").is(":visible")) window.TOUR.show("final-step");
          else if (!$(".update-btn").is(":visible")) {
            window.TOUR.show("mod-price-page-second-step");
          }
        },
        "Aggiungi date": "add-date-page-intro-step"
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var route = routes[routeName];
      if (typeof route === 'function') {
        route();
      } else {
        window.TOUR.show(route);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just refactored the code so that the TO could focus on the lower part of the constructor when searching for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

In general, before asking on a forum if some code works, there's a super easy thing you can do: try it. You can try it in a js file and run it with node or in your browser's console. Make a super minimal test and run it, you'll get your answer.

For the question "Is it possible to use switch case in a JS class constructor"  here's the minimal test I would make

```js
class A {
  constructor(a) {
    switch (a) {
      case 1:
        this.a = 'one';
        break;
      case 2:
        this.a = 'two';
        break;
      default:
        this.a = 'something else';
        break;
    }
  }
}

let first = new A(1);
let second = new A(2);
let third = new A(93);

console.log({
  test1: first.a,
  test2: second.a,
  test3: third.a
});
```

And make sure it shows

```js
{
  test1: 'one',
  test2: 'two',
  test3: 'something else'
}
```

Comment: I'd use `break` in your `case` statements but for presentation purposes only your code is valid.